# get specific user from list of #each input

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express-handlebars

I show users as list of `input type=button` using `{{#each}}` then when click function will running to get value of that input but i got undefined .

Here's the code:

**app.js**

```
app.get('/search',(req,res)=>{

    data.find({}).then(data=>{

        res.render('./search', {data: data});

    });
```

**search.handlebars**

```
     <table class="blueTable" >
            <thead>
             <tr> 
                <th>Name</th>
             </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
        {{#each data}}
                <tr> 
                    <td>       

                        <input class="button" type="button" onclick="recive()"  id="reciver" name="reciver" value="{{Name}}">
                    </td>

                 </tr>

            {{/each}}

            </tbody>
            </table>

         <script>
              function recive(){
                 var reciver = document.getElementById("reciver").value
                 console.log(reciver)
              }
         </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     <table class="blueTable" >
        <thead>
         <tr> 
            <th>Name</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
    {{#each data}}
            <tr> 
                <td>       
                    <input class="button" type="button" onclick="receive(this)" name="reciver" value="{{Name}}">
                </td>

             </tr>

        {{/each}}

        </tbody>
        </table>

     <script>
          function receive(element){
             var receiver = element.value
             console.log(receiver)
          }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why undefined in Javascript?**

> undefined is a property of the global object; i.e., it is a variable
>   in global scope. The initial value of undefined is the primitive value
>   undefined . ... A method or statement also returns undefined if the
>   variable that is being evaluated does not have an assigned value.

Basically it can't reference the {{Name}} part I assuming. **Change {{Name}} to {{this}}**

If you have a object with for example the name People

```
{
  people: [
    "Yehuda Katz",
    "Alan Johnson",
    "Charles Jolley"
  ]
}
```

Notice {{#each people}}, then change {{Name}} to {{this}}

```
<ul class="people_list">
      {{#each people}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
      {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Outputs:

```
<ul class="people_list">
  <li>Yehuda Katz</li>
  <li>Alan Johnson</li>
  <li>Charles Jolley</li>
</ul>
```

When looping through items in each, you can optionally reference the current loop index via {{@index}}

```
{{#each array}}
      {{@index}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Additionally for object iteration, {{@key}} references the current key name:

```
{{#each object}}
  {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: No problem, if you have any more issues I am more than happy to help. I will keep an eye out for your questions. Or just shoot me a tweet @raymondbpittman